# How to send a signal to all process from child process?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, fork

I 'm trying to do a socket programming example with using fork() call, my problem is: When a child process finished a job, i want to kill all other process. I think if i send a singal to others ... Is this possible or is any one tell me a way ?

Comment: Is using `kill()` and process-id of child from parent process you can kill all childs

Comment: My problem is: 
i have 4 running process(one is parent 3 are child) and they try to connect a TCP Socket...
when one of them do this i l want to kill others.

Comment: your 4 child process are as servers/or clients?

Comment: Sorry!,  Parent should be client to and your server process is septate?? Thought it looks your design is wrong to me!.. its bit trivial to code as well (at-least for me)...

Comment: Ok,Maybe you know about "4 cellphone 2 basestation and one target" socket programming project... with 2 fork() call i had 4 cellphone. if one of  child processes connect the target i want to kill others. is there a way to know them if one of proccess has connetted.? can they control each other if they connected to target?

Comment: sıkıntıyok :( :( nop I don't know, But I think you wants to target process connect  to any one cellphone process(which one winner) and other request should declined??

Comment: for this you need to send a signal to parent process either via IPC (PIPE) or signal in C (winner child process will sent signal), after getting signal from child process parent can kill all other child process.

Comment: See this: [Sending a Signal to Another Process: System Call kill()](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/signal/kill.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An usual way of kill a process group is with killpg() system call. From man pages:

"killpg() sends the signal sig to the process group pgrp."

Along with killpg(), get/setpgid might be needed also to setup a group properly.

Comment: this is more usefull. i didn't get a message. :).
Thank you very much.
thank you for your interest

Answer (score 3):

At the start of the partent (before it forks its children), call `setpgid(0,0)`. This will get the Process Group ID to the the same as the parent's PID. This PGID will be inherited by each child and any of the processes can send a signal to all processes in the group by calling `kill(signal, -getpgid(0))`.

Comment: Note that this implcitly also will send the signal to the process having called the `kill()` command.

Comment: it's usefull  but, i m getting a message...is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
killpg( 0, SIGNALTYPE);
```

You can send signal to all childs.